# Django - Google App Engine Cron 300 Error

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine, cron

I am able to successfully run my "job" by visiting "https://keel-test.appspot.com/tasks/test/". I tested the header using "http://www.webconfs.com/http-header-check.php" which returns a 200 response.

I successfully pushed the following cron.yaml to Google App Engines:

```
cron:
- description: "test"
  url: /tasks/test
  schedule: every 8 hours
```

I tried running the task via the GCP Console Task queues page. However, the GCP console says that the CRON job returns a 300 error. There are zero logs except that the page returns a 301 when run by CRON and 200 if the URL above is visited manually.

Here is the app.yaml:

```
runtime: python
env: flex
entrypoint: gunicorn config.wsgi:application

runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your cron job is hitting `/tasks/test` (without trailing slash).  Your url handler either doesn't exist or has the trailing slash.

Try hitting `https://keel-test.appspot.com/tasks/test` (no slash).  It redirects.  Thus, the `301`

Your URL handler:

`url(r'^tasks/test/$', investment_views.test, name='test_job')`

insists there be a trailing slash.  Change that to:

`url(r'^tasks/test', investment_views.test, name='test_job')`

And both (with and without slash, along with anything that starts with `test` (eg: testing123) will get to that handler.

or, use both handlers with end-of-url signaling `$` sign, if you want both to work:

```
url(r'^tasks/test$', investment_views.test, name='test_job')
url(r'^tasks/test/$', investment_views.test, name='test_job')
```

or, if you want your urls to always have the trailing slash, make sure your cron job urls obey that standard:

```
cron:
- description: "test"
  url: /tasks/test/
  schedule: every 8 hours
```

Comment: I added a trailing slack as mentioned above and reuploaded it via "gcloud app deploy cron.yaml". However, I'm still getting a 300 error. Here is the url handler "url(r'^tasks/test/$', investment_views.test, name='test_job'),".

Comment: Sorry, I confused your question with another that was using Flask.  Updating my answer for Django.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! However, I'm not following as both my cron.yaml and urls have slashes now, and I did try the code above (what you just updated it to) about 30 minutes ago. I've changed my cron handler to try both "url: /tasks/test/" and "url: /tasks/test").

Comment: Are they returning 301s?  This answer should have solved the 301 issue.  Try clearing your browser cache, or switching browsers.

Comment: Unfortunately, here is everything I've tried. https://gist.github.com/ACPK/69936f6183159ee73a92d8b565d7a7d7

Comment: I am getting `500` errors.  So, the URLs are hitting some bad code.

Comment: You're getting 500s because I tried deleting the application and starting from scratch. I'm also trying to disable the https to see if that fixes it though that isn't a permanent fix.

Comment: So, you had 2 issues, 1) URL, because `/tasks/test` does not match `r'^tasks/test/$'`  2) SSL, because cron request was redirecting to `https:`.

Comment: I think you mean that cron was redirecting to http:// which seems to be the issue. Do you have any suggestions why cron doesn't want to use SSL?

Comment: No.  Cron jobs send HTTP requests.  If you are forcing redirects to HTTPS, you will get 301s.  Your cron urls need to be accessible via HTTP.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem  with Django

URLs (urls.py):

`...
url(r'^health_check/', health_check, name='health_check'),
...`

My backend has the SSL Redirect enabled

`SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT = True`

Seeing that the app-engine crons do not follow redirects I had to disable the redirect for this one endpoint by adding the end point to the SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT variable in `settings.py`

`...
SECURE_REDIRECT_EXEMPT = [r'^health_check/']
...`